# strongswan roadwarrior doesn't route properly

Tags: ipsec, strongswan

I want to have a Linux client connect to a Linux gateway so it can access the hosts from that network (typical road warrior setup).

I have this config on the server side:

```
conn vpnserver-ikev2
        auto=add
        compress=no
        type=tunnel
        keyexchange=ikev2
        fragmentation=yes
        forceencaps=yes
        ike=aes256-sha512-modp4096
        esp=aes256-sha512
        dpdaction=clear
        dpddelay=300s
        inactivity=5s
        rekey=no
        left=%any
        leftid=vpn-test.nimblex.com
        leftcert=/etc/ipsec.d/certs/vpn-server-cert-new.pem
        leftsendcert=always
        leftsubnet=172.31.0.0/16
        right=%any
        rightid=%any
        rightauth=eap-radius
        rightsourceip=10.10.0.1/16
        rightdns=8.8.8.8
        rightsendcert=never
        eap_identity=%identity
```

And this on the client side:

```
conn ikev2-rw
    right=vpn-test.nimblex.com
    rightid=%vpn-test.nimblex.com
    rightsubnet=172.31.0.0/16
    rightauth=pubkey
    leftsourceip=%config
    leftauth=eap
    eap_identity=123456789
    auto=route
```

The authentication seem to happen just fine but when I try to ping it doesn't work.

Logs on the server side look like this when I ping:

```
04[IKE] peer requested virtual IP %any
04[CFG] assigning new lease to '123456789'
04[IKE] assigning virtual IP 10.10.0.1 to peer '123456789'
04[IKE] CHILD_SA vpnserver-ikev2{1} established with SPIs c7b0a75b_i c5fed014_o and TS 172.31.0.0/16 === 10.10.0.1/32
04[CFG] sending RADIUS Accounting-Request to server '172.31.12.234'
04[CFG] received RADIUS Accounting-Response from server '172.31.12.234'
04[ENC] generating IKE_AUTH response 4 [ AUTH CPRP(ADDR DNS) SA TSi TSr N(MOBIKE_SUP) N(ADD_4_ADDR) ]
04[NET] sending packet: from 172.31.9.29[4500] to 82.76.67.8[4500] (304 bytes)
03[JOB] deleting CHILD_SA after 5 seconds of inactivity
03[IKE] closing CHILD_SA vpnserver-ikev2{1} with SPIs c7b0a75b_i (0 bytes) c5fed014_o (0 bytes) and TS 172.31.0.0/16 === 10.10.0.1/32
03[IKE] sending DELETE for ESP CHILD_SA with SPI c7b0a75b
03[ENC] generating INFORMATIONAL request 0 [ D ]
03[NET] sending packet: from 172.31.9.29[4500] to 82.76.67.8[4500] (96 bytes)
02[NET] received packet: from 82.76.67.8[4500] to 172.31.9.29[4500] (96 bytes)
02[ENC] parsed INFORMATIONAL response 0 [ D ]
02[IKE] received DELETE for ESP CHILD_SA with SPI c5fed014
02[IKE] CHILD_SA closed
```

... and on the client side like this:

```
09[IKE] installing DNS server 8.8.8.8 via resolvconf
09[IKE] installing new virtual IP 10.10.0.1
09[IKE] CHILD_SA ikev2-rw{2} established with SPIs c5fed014_i c7b0a75b_o and TS 10.10.0.1/32 === 172.31.0.0/16
09[IKE] peer supports MOBIKE
07[NET] received packet: from 54.89.185.13[4500] to 192.168.1.4[4500] (96 bytes)
07[ENC] parsed INFORMATIONAL request 0 [ D ]
07[IKE] received DELETE for ESP CHILD_SA with SPI c7b0a75b
07[IKE] closing CHILD_SA ikev2-rw{2} with SPIs c5fed014_i (0 bytes) c7b0a75b_o (0 bytes) and TS 10.10.0.1/32 === 172.31.0.0/16
07[IKE] sending DELETE for ESP CHILD_SA with SPI c5fed014
07[IKE] CHILD_SA closed
07[ENC] generating INFORMATIONAL response 0 [ D ]
07[NET] sending packet: from 192.168.1.4[4500] to 54.89.185.13[4500] (96 bytes)
```

The 220 routing table looks like this:
`172.31.0.0/16 via 192.168.1.1 dev wlp4s0 proto static src 192.168.1.4`

iptables is flushed and ip_forward is 1.

**When connecting from the iPhone I can ping the VPN gateway but not other hosts in the network. When connecting from the linux host I can't ping even the VPN gateway.**

tcpdump on vpn gateway when it receives ping from iPhone to it looks like this:

```
19:54:17.865831 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 1, id 51961, offset 0, flags [none], proto ICMP (1), length 84)
    ip-10-10-0-1.ec2.internal > vpn-test: ICMP echo request, id 37673, seq 0, length 64
```

... when I ping from the iPhone another server in the netwrok:

```
19:55:04.220726 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 1, id 54334, offset 0, flags [none], proto ICMP (1), length 84)
    ip-10-10-0-1.ec2.internal > ip-172-31-15-66.ec2.internal: ICMP echo request, id 7727, seq 0, length 64
```

... and when I ping from the Linux host there is no ICMP traffic received on the VPN server.

On my Linux client, tcpdump looks like this:

```
23:01:21.492340 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 62233, offset 0, flags [DF], proto ICMP (1), length 84)
    10.10.0.2 > 172.31.15.66: ICMP echo request, id 21102, seq 1, length 64
```

What am I missing?

Comment: The route looks wrong (wrong source IP, should be the virtual IP), the tcpdump output on the client looks wrong (why 10.10.0.2 when 10.10.0.1 is assigned as virtual IP). Also due to the inactivity timeout the CHILD_SA is destroyed pretty much immediately.

Comment: It was 10.10.0.2 because I connected the phone and IPs changed since I copy/pasted the tcpdump thing a few minutes apart. I don't think that it matters that the CHILD_SA is destroyed because it gets recreated when there is activity. The 2 main questions here:
1. Why the route is wrong on Linux?
2. Why on iOS it only goes to the router and it can't reach any server from the network?

Comment: Try increasing the log level for _knl_ to 2. Also read [Forwarding and Split-Tunneling](https://wiki.strongswan.org/projects/strongswan/wiki/ForwardingAndSplitTunneling).

Comment: As you can see in the configs I am already trying to use split-tunneling by setting rightsubnet on the gateway and the same leftsubnet on the Linux client. The outpul with knl set to 2 is this: https://hastebin.com/abifimogec.log

Comment: Didn't notice this before, but you currently can't combine `auto=route` with `leftsourceip=%config` ([#2162](https://wiki.strongswan.org/issues/2162)). And you should read the complete page, not just the title.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As ecdsa suggested it was incorrect to use `auto=route` if `leftsourceip=%config`.

It should have been `auto=start`.